# Ideas to save data database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, joomla

I have an web application in which I need to pass data created from Joomla content manager on one page (page A) into another page(page B)

Suppose it is a news article, page B is the main fisrt page of my site eg. `http://mysite.com/index.php`,

In order for this to be done automatically (that is after the administrator created and pressed Save the article), I will save it into a database, anytime the main site is called, I embed a php code to connect and read and process content from all the articles and insert it into the news section to display them as expected.

Is this a good feasible approach ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.  Use $_GET or $_POST .

Comment: pLease clarify more for me to go

Comment: Since php scripts does not support user interaction, you need to use ajax in your `page A` for this. Here is good article for you : `http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php`